# Practice lodash on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

I am trying to practice my lodash skills on jsfiddle.net.

I am trying simple copy paste of the following code

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], function(n) { return n * 3; });
```

By setting the framework options library to lodash 2.2.1 and pressing the run button however nothing happens i dont get any output any ideas please ?

Comment: Can you link to your jsFiddle?

Comment: I'm getting a `ReferenceError: _ is not defined` when I try. JSFiddle was down earlier. This might have something to do with that.

Comment: [Underscore appears to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/mpnbj28p/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not outputting anything to see.

jsFiddle !== console. If you want to see what happens, you need to log it.

```
var x = _.map([1, 2, 3], function(n) { return n * 3; });
console.log(x);
```

This also assumes you have the fiddle set up correctly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wsny0r2/)

Comment: Yes your answer is correct i was thinking the console is not required.Looks like that is not the case

Answer (score 2):

Here is a page you can use to test your Lodash code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io) (same concept as jsFiddle). All JavaScript executions are kept in browser.

https://codepen.io/travist/full/jrBjBz/

Here is the code I used in this to make this happen.

```
var code = $('#code').val();
var result = null;
try {
  result = eval(code);
}
catch (err) {
  result = err.message;
}
if (!result) {
  result = 'No result';
}
if (typeof result === 'object') {
  try {
    result = JSON.stringify(result, null, '   '); 
  }
  catch (err) {
    result = err.message;
  }
}
$('#result').text(result);
```

Disclaimer: I built this codepen